# How to install Parse Server on CentOS Server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, server, parse-server

I've got a server: CentOS 7.5, Intel i7, 16GB RAM, 120GB SSD

Is it possible to run Parse Server on it? If so how can I install it from WHM & Cpanel?

I searched about it. But most of the articles are about deploying Parse Server to Heroku, Digital Ocean, Back4app, etc.

Comment: Looks like your question not for this site. Try to ask on 'Unix & Linux" or "Superuser".

Comment: I've asked on them too.

Answer (score 0):

Back4App is a Baas and provide all Parse Server Configuration with just one click. There have Backups Scalable Design, Redundancy, Backups, Host your Website and others. You can check more about it at [this guide](https://www.back4app.com/docs/parse-create-new-app).

Comment: Thank you. I previously used Back4app. But now I've got my own server. I'm trying to find a way installing/running Parse Server on my own server.